# Kafka how to enable logging in Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have written a test application to experiment with Kafka. I am now trying to enable logging.

I don't know too much about how logging is done in Java applications, but my understanding is that typically, a framework would be used. Some examples include:

- log4j
- slf4j
- logback

My understanding is that, in most cases, these logging frameworks define an interface library as well as an implementation library, so that they can be mixed and matched.

For example, if Kafka uses `logging-api-A`, then it would be possible to use `logging-impl-B` for the actual implementation, while maintaining compatibility with the Kafka implementation code which calls the API defined for `logging-api-A`.

Further, my understanding is that typically a library would be required to "glue together" one logging API framework with one logging implementation framework. This library is an adapter of some kind which enables interoperability.

---

## How can I enable logging in my client Java code which uses Kafka?

If I call Kafka code from my Java program, and there is a failure, I would expect to be able to see some logging information printed to `stdout`. Even in the case where there is no failure, I would still expect to be able to configure logging so that info or debug messages are shown logging details of what is being done. (Eg: sending messages to Kafka should produce some kind of log, so should consuming messages. Connecting or disconnecting, etc...)

At the moment I don't know which framework Kafka uses for logging. There is conflicting information available online. Some articles suggest log4j is used, some suggest slf4j and some suggest logback is used after a recent update. So I'm confused about how logging is actually done by Kafka.

This information is made harder to find, because Kafka itself can be used as an output for logging. For example, you might write an application, and rather than dumping logs to a file, you might want that logging information to be dumped to a Kafka topic instead. Hence it is very hard to search for information, because the word "log" is used for multiple purposes.

---

## Test Code

This isn't especially relevant, but here's some test code I have been using if it helps.

```
package com.myname.kafkaexample.KafkaExample;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:29092");
        properties.setProperty("default.topic", "hello-world-topic");
        properties.setProperty("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        properties.setProperty("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
        
        String topicName = "hello-world-topic";
        String key = "testkey";
        String message = "Hello Kafka! (Message String)";
        
        ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, key, message);
        producer.send(producerRecord);
        producer.close();
    }

}
```

And the `pom.xml`...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.myname.kafkaexample</groupId>
  <artifactId>KafkaExample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>KafkaExample</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
      <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>com.myname.kafkaexample.KafkaExample.Main</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.5.0</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.myname.kafkaexample.KafkaExample.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>

  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Kafka includes `reload4j` as an optional dependency (a replacement for log4j 1.x) after a recent update, not logback

Answer (score 2):

Kafka uses Slf4j as the logging facade. This library allows you to choose which logging implementation you want to use, so you just need to add a dependency onto the appropriate slf4j adaptor library, as described [here](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping).

Your pom.xml is using log4j (v2) as the logging implementation and appears to be using the correct logging adaptor (log4j-slf4j2-impl) as described [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl.html).

Comment: According to this diagram, it looks like my POM contains everything required. Eg: If I want to use the logback logging implementation (which I do because it is already used by something else) then I would need `slf4j-api`, `logback-classic` and `logback-core`. All of which I have, and yet I do not get any output from Kafka in terms of logging...  https://www.slf4j.org/images/concrete-bindings.png

Comment: Are you providing a config file for your logging lib (e.g. log4j.xml or logbavck.xml)?

Answer (score 1):

> these logging frameworks define an interface library

Yes. Slf4j is the interface. The others are 2 implementations, but there are others like `java.util.logging` (JUL).

You also need a [binding library](https://slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping) for a specific implentation.

> There is conflicting information available online. Some articles suggest log4j is used, some suggest slf4j

Both are accurate. log4j **1.x** (not 2, like you've added) / reload4j is the implementation that Kafka uses, but uses it via the slf4j interfaces.

> Hence it is very hard to search for information, because the word "log" is used for multiple purposes

Writing to Console stdout/stderr, files, or Kafka is done with ["appenders"](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/mom/kafka/KafkaAppender.html) in log4j terms, not a "logger".

> there is a failure, I would expect to be able to see some logging information printed to stdout

Only if you have a valid log *file*. Java does not include one for you.

For example, you would need `src/main/resources/log4j2.xml` (create resources directory in your Maven project if not exists) to have the log4j2 library you've added to log anything, anywhere.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="DEBUG"> <!-- everything as debug -->
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="INFO"/>  <!-- except internal kafka packages -->
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Can I use both `log4j` at the same time in the same application (binary) as another logging library such as `logback`. The reason I ask this is that at some point I will want to use Kafka in conjunction with another library, and that other library is currently working, and writing to logs, with logback.

Comment: Looking at this again, why would I need to create a `log4j2.xml` config file, if I wanted to use logback as the implementation?

Comment: Your original question included log4j2 dependencies, so that's what I answered with. It's actually recommended to use that over logback, I believe. But regardless, you can add `log4j.properties`, or `logback.xml`, sure. It depends which library you're using. Any external library should also be using Slf4j, not explicitly logback

Comment: This is still a point of confusion for me. What is is which dictates which particular "method" of logging will be used? (log4j vs logback etc...) Is it the existence of the configuration xml files? In which case, what happens if there is more than one? Or, maybe more likely, is it the existence of a dependency in the pom? Again, if so, what happens if more than once dependency is specified. Does the question make sense? To clarify your question however, I am writing something where there are two libraries in use. One is Kafka, the other is our own internal thing which uses logback. (I think.)

Comment: It's the dependency that determines which filename you need to use. The documentation of each library discusses "resolution ordering". For example, log4j2 accepts properties or yaml files as well. Meanwhile, I've only seen xml files with logback. And you can either place on the classpath, or pass as a JVM system property at runtime. I've never tried using two libraries, but Slf4j will throw a warning if it it finds multiple implementations of its classes

Comment: Ok thanks for that, from your comment I take it that if I am using multiple different libraries and pulling them all together, then I need to direct all of those libraries to use a single "backend" for logging, in other words, a single actual implementation for logging. In my specific case, that would (probably) be logback, because one library in particular seems to be strongly coupled to logback and we haven't been able to figure out how to "decouple" it - although obviously that seems like something that *should* be possible.

Comment: That's right. You can always use a maven exclusion rule to remove logback, for example, from external dependencies, assuming the code itself does not import logback specific packages